# Logging multiple scripts from the same directory in python

Tags: python, logging

I have two python scripts in the same directory. I try to catch logging messages from both of them:

```
#script.py
import requests
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Downloader:
    
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        
    def download(self):
        logger.debug(f'Downloading {self.url}')
        req = requests.get(self.url, timeout=1)
        return req
```

```
#main.py
import logging
from script import Downloader

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.debug('create object')

d = Downloader('https://www.google.com')
res = d.download()
```

Basically I want to get rid of the debug-messages from the `requests`-module, so using `logging.basicConfig()` is not an option. But the way I do it, I do not get the debug-message from the imported script. Apparently because in script.py `__name__` is not `main.script`.

How can I achieve this without hard coding anything to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a different file (e.g. `logger.py`):

```py
import logging

def setup_logger(name, logfile, formatter, stream_handler=False, level=logging.DEBUG):
    """Function to create loggers."""

    file_handler   = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
    stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler()

    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    stdout_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)

    if not logger.handlers:
        logger.setLevel(level)
        logger.addHandler(file_handler)
        if stream_handler:
            logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)

    return logger

# Example formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s -> %(message)s\n')

# Generate the log object
log = setup_logger('logger_name', 'path_to_logfile', formatter)
```

Import this `log` object from your other modules to use it: `from logger import log`